# Laravel 5.4 save NULL to database not working

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

The following code results in an empty value inside the database and when I get it out of the database its an empty String.

```
$customer->update(['company' => NULL]);
```

Comment: and do you want NULL when you get it out from db?

Comment: @dparoli yes, the field is optional and it could be null, so if it is null I would like to get null and not an empty string, and an empty field in database

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should consider 3 things:

1) Make sure `company` column in `nullable` in your table. If it's not it won't be possible to put `null` in there.

2) Make sure you have in `$fillable` property of `Customer` model column `company`

3) Verify you don't have any mutator in your `Customer` model - so verify you don't have `setCompanyAttribute` method that might change value automatically to empty string if it's set to null

Comment: thank you for your answer, I found the error had a mutator for company ://

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**

If you want a field inside the database to be null and you do not use a mutator everything is fine.

Are you using a mutator, in my case the following snippet.

```
public function setCompanyAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['company'] = ucfirst($value);
}
```

Then you need to check if $value is null and then set it manually to null otherwise it will be an empty string.

To do that automatically on every model you can set the empty string back to null inside your EventServiceProvider.

```
Event::listen('eloquent.saving: *', function ($eventName, array $data) {
    $attributes = [];

    foreach ($data as $model) {
        foreach( $model->getAttributes() as $key => $value ) {
            $attributes[$key] = (is_string($value) && $value === '') ? null : $value;
       }

        $model->setRawAttributes($attributes);
    }

    return true;
});
```

It's important to first check all attributes from the model and set it to a temporary array. Now inside the setAttribute() method on the model instance the checks are done if a mutator exists. But thats exactly what you do not want, because it would set all fields with a definied mutator to an empty sting. Instead use setRawAttribute so the old attributes are overwritten with the ones from the temporary array.

This is safe to do because if the checked value isn't an empty string the already existing value is taken for that field. Otherwise if it's an empty string then null is set.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is quite strange to change accepted to yours and present code that was not presented in original question

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek sry I changed it back. Thought it would be helpful for next reader to see how I fixed it. Your answer lists some parts that must be reviewed, but mine presents a possible solution.